# Conditionally abort a release build

Tags: xcode, compilation

I'd like Xcode to abort release builds when it detects an arbitrary comment tag (*eg. `// FIXME:*`) that I'd place in the code. Does anyone do this or something similar? I want to avoid releasing apps in an incomplete state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a comment, you can use:

```
#warning FIXME: this needs to be finished
```

You can put anything you want after the `#warning`. When you compile, the compiler will spit out a compiler warning with whatever text you put after `#warning`. This is really affective if you setup your project so that warnings are treated as errors (I only accept 100% clean builds).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
#error Error message here.
```